# VBA Identification of Connected Shapes in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am trying to develop a VBA solution within Excel that can identify which shapes are connected to eachother within a worksheet via a standard connector line.

[image: shapes example]

For example, in the snippet attached, I need to create a code that can identify that the control square is connected to the two red circles (titled Risk 1 and Risk 2) and output the following in a message box: "Risk 1 and Risk 2 are connected to Control". I have been able to find code to add connector lines however I cannot figure out how to identify connected shapes. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! I have also attached the code that I have been able to find thus far.

```
Sub QuickConnect( )
    Dim s1 As Shape, s2 As Shape, conn As Shape
    
    ' Create a shape
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCube, 100, 10, 50, 60)
    
    ' Create another shape
    Set s2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCan, 50, 100, 50, 60)

    ' Create connector with arbitrary coordinates
    Set conn = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    ' Connect shapes
    conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect s1, 1
    conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect s2, 1
    
    ' Connect via shortest path (changes connection sites)
    conn.RerouteConnections
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.connectorformat.endconnectedshape) and [ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.connectorformat.beginconnectedshape) to achieve what you want.

**LOGIC:**

1. Loop through all connector shapes.
2. Create a Unique collection of shapes to which other shapes are connected with.
3. Get the Beginning and the Ending shape names.
4. Find the relation i.e WHO is connected to WHO.

**CODE:**

I have commented the code but if you still have questions then feel free to ask.

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Change this if your shapes include the below text
Const mySep As String = "MySep"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shpConnector As Shape
    Dim shpConnectorCount As Long
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim tmpAr As Variant, itm As Variant
    Dim colConnector As New Collection
    Dim msg As String
    Dim finalOutput As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Count the number of connector shapes
        For Each shpConnector In .Shapes
            If shpConnector.Connector Then shpConnectorCount = shpConnectorCount + 1
        Next shpConnector
        
        '~~> If not found then exit sub
        If shpConnectorCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        '~~> Resize array based on connector count
        ReDim tmpAr(1 To shpConnectorCount)
        
        For Each shpConnector In .Shapes
            With shpConnector
                If .Connector Then
                    '~~> Unique collection of shapes to which other
                    '~~> shapes are connected with
                    On Error Resume Next
                    colConnector.Add CStr(.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Name), _
                    CStr(.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Name)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                    '~~> Store Starting shape and End Shape in an array
                    tmpAr(i) = .ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Name & mySep _
                    & .ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Name
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End With
        Next
        
        '~~> Loop through the unique collection and the array to create
        '~~> Our necessary output
        For Each itm In colConnector
            msg = ""
            For i = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
                If Split(tmpAr(i), mySep)(1) = itm Then
                    msg = msg & "," & Split(tmpAr(i), mySep)(0)
                End If
            Next i
            finalOutput = finalOutput & vbNewLine & Mid(msg, 2) & " is/are connected to " & itm
        Next itm
    End With
    
    MsgBox Mid(finalOutput, 2)
End Sub
```

**IN ACTION:**

[image]

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

Comment: You cannot blame the rain now. How can I/you make it work if the shapes are in a group?

Comment: Ungroup-and then regroup :)

Answer (score 4):

Therefore you need to loop through all shapes, check if they are a connector (yes, connector lines are shapes too). And then you can check which shapes are connected by this connector line:

The property `.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape` gives you the shape at one end of the connector line and `.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape` the shape on the other end.

Checkout this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestConnections()
    Dim shp As Variant
    For Each shp In Shapes 'loop through all shapes            
        If shp.Connector = msoTrue Then 'check if current shape is a connector
            'BeginConnectedShape is the shape on the beginning side of the connector
            'EndConnectedShape is the shape on the ending side of the connector
            Debug.Print shp.Name _
                        & " connects " & _
                        shp.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Name _
                        & " with " & _
                        shp.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Name
        End If
    Next shp 
End Sub
```

For the following shapes

[image]

it outputs

```
Curved Connector 3 connects Cube 1 with Can 2
Curved Connector 6 connects Cube 5 with Can 2
```

Comment: Great solution. You could simplify the code by looping with "For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes". Then you can refer to shp from there without needing an index or a specific set.

Comment: Great. You only need a worksheet, at least `ActiveSheet`, with a dot in front of the two occurrences of `Shapes` to make it work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes, or put it in the desired worksheet's scope instead of a module and it will work as it is. But as you suggested full referencing is always better.

Comment: @RenierWessels well, of course you are completely right. I fixed that. How could I oversee that, probably it was too early :o

Comment: i had no idea. Tested it, of course. And as you already know, you're right. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @VBasic2008 well, you were totally right that a full reference to a workbook would definitely be a benefit. Just spared it out because I didn't want to make it unnecessarily longer than it needed to be.

Comment: If you get everything on a platter, what will you learn. I like this *You'll have to work for it* approach.